# version number more than the current one. Unable to install

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version, assemblies

I am trying to install a new MSi file in my computer. Assemblies GAC Deploy.msi. The msi build version number is ending with 5563. However, I already have a GAC deploy msi installed with a version number greater than this. This might have happened because multiple users might have done a build on the same assembly which caused the version number to increase. but the changes I made are the latest, and I am not able to install these changes in my instance because of the version number being less than the number in my shown in installed programs. How can I change this number so that the instance will think the file I am installing now is the latest one? Help please.

[You can see that there is an error which says installation failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoYiA.png)

[Because you can see that the version number installed on my PC is more than what I am trying to install.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH2UK.png)

Answer (score 0):

By changing the DetectNewerInstalledVersion property to false.